# JavaScript/jQuery to load more from MySQL?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I searched Google on how to do this, and I got the following link:
http://www.9lessons.info/2009/12/twitter-style-load-more-results-with.html

That is exactly what I want to do, however it's rather confusing to me so I can't work out how to implement it properly to my current file.

My current query is as follows.

```
if (!$query = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM confessions ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10")) {
    echo '<strong>Error:</strong> '.mysql_error().'';
} else {
    echo '<div id="posts">';
    while ($q = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $id = $q['id'];
        $name = $q['confession'];
        $date = date("j M Y", strtotime($q['date']));
        echo '<div class="confession" ';
        echo '>';
            echo '<table>';
                echo '<tr style="width:700px;">';
                    echo '<td style="width:100px;font-weight:lighter;font-style:italic;font-size:95%;">'.$date.'</td>';
                    echo '<td style="width:600px;">'.$name.'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            echo '</table>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Obviously that just grabs the data of the last 10 rows in that table, and as far as I know I just need some JavaScript to remember the limit, and how many it grabbed, so it can grab the next lot.

Is it possible somoene can give me a link to help me explain it more, or write up some code (from the link I gave) that'll help?

Comment: What you're looking for is called paging.

Comment: Not sure why people are so quick to down vote things like this.  This is a valid question where someone has little understanding of current code and is exactly why sites like this were created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Addressing Questions

> Obviously that just grabs the data of the last 10 rows in that table, and as far as I know I just need some JavaScript to remember the limit, and how many it grabbed, so it can grab the next lot.

Right, your demo page does this with the Javascript variable `ID`, which they send to the ajax_more.php

> Is it possible somoene can give me a link to help me explain it more, or write up some code (from the link I gave) that'll help?

That is not necessary.

---

### Clarifying Demo

The demo's main page is `loadmore.php`, which creates the html page and coincidentally also lists the first batch from the query.  It uses the button (the anchor link, not the link's box) to store the most recent `ID`, in your case the button's ID will be your date (***Note:*** your date better be a unique field, or you may not return all results).

When a user clicks the "more" link, the JavaScript gets its `id` and then passes that on to the `ajax_more.php`, which it uses in the query to get the next batch of results since the last query, based on the ID you sent it (the SQL `order by` is important).

---

### More

1. As @hakre suggested, what you are referring to is called "paging" and most databases have their on implementation of it, such that you don't need to re-query the database if you keep the connection open.
   Also in mySQL you can supply the length and the offset, so instead of storing the ID and using  less than, you can store the amount of records already retrieved (referred to as an offset).  Example:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM <your_table> LIMIT <offset>, <length>

   -- In Use:
   SELECT * FROM confessions LIMIT 40, 10
   -- 40 is the value that you passed to ajax_more.php via AJAX
   ```
2. **Warning:** what the example doesn't tell you is the security implications of how they're querying the database.  You're exposing user input (through JavaScript) directly to the database, without scrubbing the data or using any special use of parameter passing.  This is a big security hole and opens you put to SQL Injection attacks, which are basically holes that allow users to put their own SQL commands, that can gain access to your database, or even entire system.

Comment: Thanks!! :) The way you've written it explains it a lot more, and I can actually understand it. I'll change it to use ID rather than date, that way they're definitely unique. Thanks again :)

Comment: You basically had it all, I don't think their php pages were optimally named for a tutorial.  It should have had an `index.php`

Comment: I've got it working, however I load the page with the MySQL query with this code: $('#loaddiv').load('feed.php');

Because of this, it reloads the page every 20 seconds (the time I set) so it sets the LIMIT back to normal. Is there any way I can stop this? For example, how would I go about creating a session to do this?

Comment: You could stop that using an http session, the easiest way is storing a session id in a cookie, query string param, or hidden text field.  Then for that session you could store a variable (something like `row_position`).  On the other hand, you could also **avoid a session** and pass the offset param with your statement (`... .load('feed.php',{offset: typeof $('.more').attr('id') === 'undefined'?0:$('.more').attr('id'))`) - *of course, you probably want to cache `$('.more')` somewhere before hand.

Comment: Thanks!! :) I'll see if I can put it all together

Comment: I forgot the ending `}` the format should be `.load('...',{...})`

Answer (score 0):

Your query: `SELECT * FROM confessions ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10` has the LIMIT statement 10 without a comma. that means you just get the first 10 results.

Just watch the example on http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm and you will get it.

Comment: When I was using the jQuery from that link I provided I change the LIMIT 10 to the limit variable in the link. :)

Comment: It didn't work. At all. I've very little knowledge of JavaScript so I was hoping someone could help me with the JavaScript to get the last LIMIT and adjust the new LIMIT to show the next lot of results.